# $result only one row then convert into session

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

i am trying to query one single row from a table 'account'. I kind mess up with the MYSQLI so i need some advice. How can i do that?

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$passcode."' LIMIT 1";
$result = $link->query($query) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$numrow = $result->num_rows;
$res = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

After the query i want to copy the data to a session, i am doing like that:

```
    session_start();  
    $tableau = array($res['cod_acc'],$res['username'],$res['password']); 
    $_SESSION['tableau'] = $tableau;
```

And after these, how can i print the data?

```
    $tableau = $_SESSION['tableau']; 
    echo "$tableau['username']";
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Is there any error message? What is not working?

Comment: that should work as intended? what error message do you get?

Comment: Y r u mixing procedural and object oriented together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From your question:**

> how can i print the data?

First of all you need to add `error_reporting()` on in your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You are saving values in an array for `$_SESSION`:

```
$tableau = array($res['cod_acc'],$res['username'],$res['password']); 
$_SESSION['tableau'] = $tableau;
```

If you look your session array it's not an **associative array**.

So you can not get the result like:

```
$tableau = $_SESSION['tableau']; 
echo $tableau['username'];
```

**Solution:**

You can get username from session array as:

```
echo $tableau[1]; // username on second index.
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want associative index than you need to use associative array as:

```
$tableau = array(
"cod_acc"=>$res['cod_acc'],
"username"=>$res['username']); 
$_SESSION['tableau'] = $tableau;
```

Now you can use as you need. Note that I am removing password field from session I think its not need.

**Side note:**

I don't know why are mixing Procedural and Objected Oriented style together.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in some other line code, sorry for the post. But thanks guys.